# Userform Input Small hyphen & Long hyphen? (✱Using symbols in Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, character, symbols

I am entering a string in a Userform in Excel-VBA from the user side of the form. I would want to know how to enter the Long Hyphen.

The Small Hyphen would be <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><del>-</del></kbd> the (the minus sign button next to <kbd>0</kbd>).

How would you enter the Long Hyphen on the form as I am doing a string match in my VBA code on the back-end?  It can be entered with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0150</kbd>, but is there another simpler way?

If the option of entering the Long Hyphen doesn't work then I will handle this value on the back-end through a find and replace method or something in VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one *"**Hyphen**"*...    It's part of a **ᖴᗩᗰᎥᒪƳ ᴏғ ᑕᕼᗩᖇᗩᑕ丅ᗴᖇᔕ** called ***Dashes***.

<sub>*Examples:*</sub>

- Hyphen [`-`] (-)
- Minus sign [`−`] (−)
- En dash [`–`] (–)
- Em dash [`—`] (—)

### <sub>✱ Your browser might render them differently, but the fonts above are *supposed* to be</sub> [`Consolas or Courier 13px`] <sub>and</sub> (Arial or Helvetica 15px).  <sub>While they all kind of look the same `in this font`, those *are* four different characters.</sub>

The characters can be copy/pasted directly from here  `- − – —` into Excel (but *not* to the the VBA Editor), or can be produced **along with [`136,686`](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/HowMany.html) other [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters**, either:

- with a worksheet formula, using the [**`ᴜɴɪᴄʜᴀʀ`** function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765924.aspx):

  ```
  =UNICHAR(9733)  'produces a [★] star character.
  ```
- programmatically with VBA, using the [**`ChrW`** function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chr-function):

  ```
  Range("A1") = ChrW(9743) 'puts a wee [☏] rotary phone in cell A1.
  ```

---

### *More about dashes —*

- **[What they are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes)**
- **[How to use them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:How_to_make_dashes)**

---

### ***"Stealing"*** Unicode characters from websites

There are all sorts of handy Unicode symbols — so many that it can be hard to find "just" the right one.

However you can (*and will!*) find other Unicode symbols on web pages that you want to use programmatically.  All you need is the symbol's code, which can be determined easily:

> - Copy/paste the symbol from your browser (being careful to copy only the single character; no spaces, etc.) into a cell in Excel
> - then, go to VBA's Immediate Window ( <sup><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd></sup>→<sub><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd></sub> ), type:
>
>   ```
>   MsgBox AscW([a1])
>   ```
>
> ...(Where `A1` is the cell with the character). Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the character's Unicode code will display.

You could also use Windows' built-in [Character Map](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/charmap/) utility, or one of many third-party [browser plug-ins](https://www.google.ca/search?q=browser%20plug%20in%20to%20get%20unicode%20from%20symbol%20on%20web%20page).  You can even paste a symbol directly into Google to learn more about it:
[image: Google search for ☮ symbol]

---

Finally, no discussion on the topic of [Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) would be complete without links to:

### **[The Unicode Consortium (`unicode.org`)](http://www.unicode.org/)** <sub><sup>*and*,</sup></sub>

### **[“ȶɦɛ   Ⓣⓔⓧⓣ ”](https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html)**  <sub><sup><sub>(Yes, those are all *plain text* characters.)</sub></sup></sub>

...and if you're looking for a unique gift, or just want your name to go down in history for something that *really* matters, you can even [**adopt** a Unicode character](http://unicode.org/consortium/adopt-a-character.html?referrer=justicewire), starting at $100 ᴜsᴅ!

---

<sub>Special thanks to [Vinton Cerf](https://research.google.com/pubs/author32412.html) for adopting the Unicode **[Leonard Nimoy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Nimoy) *["Live Long and Prosper"](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%96%96)* symbol.**</sub>